# Any Online compiler you know for C or other languages?

Tags: c, online-compilation

Any **online C compiler** that you know which can do the following:

- Compile and execute the C programs online
- File handling
- System functions like `exec()`, `system()`, `fork()`

Or any compiler which does not need installation procedure (I mean that you can just copy paste a folder to run the compiler **easily**)

Note:Please do not propose Turbo C.I know some online compilers at [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) (gcc).
I was using [codeide.com](http://www.codeide.com) but its out of service now I think.
And as asked above online compiler will be a best advice that you can give for me.

My environment is Windows ... Thanks in advance.
Any advices on other Language compilers are also invited

Comment: Do you mean execute the code on the server? Or return the compiled exe in the response?

Comment: any way will be useful
Even I want an exe which can be passed with some argc,argvs

Comment: My guess is NO. Executing arbitrary code on a server, what a security nightmare. Perhaps someone would let you compile and download an exe, but that's it.

Comment: Why on earth would you need a compiler that works exclusively in a browser?

Answer (score 6):

Just install something like [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/). It's seriously not worth messing around with an online compiling site if you're going to be compiling files on any sort of regular basis.

Comment: just now i tried tcc its good in such 900kb size its excellent
but my needs demand an online compiler. ok thank u for ur suggestion

Comment: What could you possibly be doing that *demands* an online compiler?

Comment: I've been forced to use an online compiler in the past. Sure, I could have built a C compiler that runs on a Nintendo DS and targets that platform. But it was way easier to send the C file to a server via the internet and compile it using devKitPro, and send the resulting ROM back to the DS. I can almost guarantee this isn't what he's doing, but you get the point, right? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Comeau** has an [online C/C++ compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/), but it's mainly to evaluate their compiler.

or **cygwin**

I'd rather recommend to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you'll get an unix-like environment, with gcc. Then setting up a Makefile - or even just a shell script - to be able to compile is not a big deal.

Comment: I saw Comeau also but its mainly to evaluate their compiler as u said.
But for me installation is not an option, I need one like an online compiler

Comment: Manoj Doubts, why is an installation not an option ? You have restrictions in installing software (not your machine) ? Maybe a portable solution ?

Comment: How about a Live-CD? http://www.livecdlist.com/?pick=All&showonly=Development

Answer (score 3):

You asked for other languages: Here's one for **Lisp** (not a compiler, but an interpreter)

[Online Lisp interpreter in Flash](http://www.solve-et-coagula.com/As3Lisp.html)

Answer (score 3):

[rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode)

Comment: Best online compiler!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my answer is a bit late, but we have created an online compiler and IDE where you can run and create your files using just a browser.

At the moment we support a few languages (C, C++, ObjC, Java, Pascal, Fortran) and a simple file system, but we will enable many more features for better coding and debugging during the near future.

All the features offered at the moment are completely free and there is no registration needed (you can register though in order to keep your files online).

You can try our service here: [www.sourcelair.com](http://www.sourcelair.com)

Comment: Link does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: Hello Sharik, sourceLair is up and running, the link is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

[**DJGPP Public Access Cross-Compiler**](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/compile/) (C/C++, DOS32, based on GCC)

Comment: Its good. It is giving executables back. But it is giving heavy .exe back like simple hello world gives 44.8kb where as the same was 1.5kb in tcc and other compilers. ok so this online compiler is ok but some what heavy but portable without installation where as tcc is with installation.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

yet another online compiler:

http://cmpe150-1.cmpe.boun.edu.tr

It supports sytax highlight, indentation etc. I wrote it as a part of my MS thesis

PS: did not test fork command

Comment: Requires Internet Explorer? Seriously?

Comment: sadly :( I did not have time for completing the xbrowser version. Working on it...

Comment: worked on it, cross browser now

Comment: Wondrful, I am loving it :-). I tried it and it worked splendid (better than any online compiler in my opinion). Tested `printf("Helloo\b Dear");`, unlike other online compilers, this one did gave the expected output. Just one thingy(if this can be added), instead of opening a new window/tab, what if the result can be displayed and an option to download the `.exe` if one opts for it.

Answer (score 1):

We have another compiler for C and C++ here: http://www.codepad.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing for C. For other languages, this is a [ruby interpreter](http://tryruby.hobix.com/). But honestly the best online development environment is the browser itself. Javascript is an advanced language. Combined with technologies like CSS and DHTML and frameworks like jQuery or Prototype you can build graphics applications. It is not hard to find debuggers (like Firebug) also.

Of course you can't interact with the file system. To overcome this  you could write a plug-in for a browser (notably Firefox). There are many resources available for this and although it is not as straight forward as pure javascript, it is easier than most people believe.

Answer (score 0):

For Python and Sage, try out http://live.codenode.org. It is also open source under the BSD license, so you can be download and run it from your own computer, more info is here: http://codenode.org

Answer (score 0):

just a sudgestion.

I do not know why you do not want simply to install a compiler. However did you considered the possibility of using a portable one?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_C_Compiler

best,
Ste

Answer (score 0):

One of the better lists for C++ is [`isocpp Getting Started`](http://isocpp.org/get-started) page. Unfortunately `Cameau's` seems to be disabled for now. `LiveWorkspace` has been in maintenance mode for a while and it is not clear when it is coming back, which is unfortunate since it has a simple interface and when it was working allowed you to switch between `gcc`, `clang` and `intel` very easily.

Of the ones that are left [`Coliru`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) is the most powerful, you have a full command line available and you can save files and therefore uses multiple files in your project.

The `isocpp` list somehow is missing [`codepad`](http://codepad.org/) which although rather primitive along with `Coliru` allows you to use [`boost`](http://www.boost.org/).

`Coliru`, `ideone` and `codepad` all support many other languages as well. The list of languages supported by `ideone` and `codepad` is pretty large and is obvious on the main pages with `Coliru` you don't have a list but besides `C` and `C++` it also supports `python`, `perl` and `ruby`.