# Online compilers/runtime for Java, C++, Python and ObjC?

Tags: java, c++, python, compiler-construction, runtime

Does anyone know of a good online compiler/runtime (for C++, Java, Python, ObjC etc.) that I can access on the web?

What I'm looking for is something that would allow me to type in a program in a web form and to run the program and see the results online.

(Let's not get into the why for now. Suffice it to say for the moment that I don't always have access to a compiler/runtime, and firing up an IDE is just overkill for testing out some code snippets)

I know of codepad.org -- but I'm looking for something better.

Comment: Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523568/any-online-compiler-you-know-for-c-or-other-languages

Comment: How is "how do I do coding on someone else's computer?" NOT programming related?

Comment: It's random theft of services.  If they want help with algorithm, data structure, language or library, that's fine.  But "how do I code on the web?" is akin to "help me buy the 'best' programming laptop."

Comment: Why is it "random theft of services" to use a web service someone has set up for that purpose?

Comment: I don't know if it's better, but [rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://codepad.org/

> codepad.org is an online
>   compiler/interpreter, and a simple
>   collaboration tool. Paste your code
>   below, and codepad will run it and
>   give you a short URL you can use to
>   share it in chat or email.

Languages:

C
  C++
  D
  Haskell
  Lua
  OCaml
  PHP
  Perl
  Plain Text
  Python
  Ruby
  Scheme
  Tcl

Comment: How on earth can this be marked as answer?? The question explicitly mentions Java, which is NOT included in the languages supported by codepad.org, and the OP expliciely says he already knows codepad.org and needs something better...

Comment: I didn't notice the OP already knows about codepad until after I wrote the answer - so my bad on that one

Comment: codepad.org seems to be dead for some days, do you have any news about it?

Answer (score 40):

[ideone](http://ideone.com) is something better but what particular advence do you need?

Comment: This is great for Java. Been looking for something like this.

Comment: +1 I was surprised codepad didn't support Java. So I googled, and your answer was perfect.

Comment: Ah, but the section where ideone fails for me is it cannot run GUI code, and it cannot have interaction with the program during running, AFAIR

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you can use http://sagenb.org.  This is a free open source online Google Docs-like programming notebook environment, which I provide (thanks to a generous grant from the National Science Foundation).  Once you create an account and create a new worksheet, click on the box (fourth from left) labeled "Sage" and change it to Python.  Now all the code you type in is evaluated using Python.   The main drawback is that there are well over 30,000 users of this resource, so sometimes it is slow.

Answer (score 3):

I found this online java compiler and runner. It works in realtime and also with threads. Amazing !
http://www.browxy.com

Answer (score 2):

For C++, you could try [CodeControl](http://www.codecontrol.blogspot.com/2007/08/online-c-c-compiler.html), [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) or the one from [code.vcer.net](http://code.vcer.net/).

Answer (score 2):

[This one](http://tryruby.hobix.com/) is good for ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source one: http://codenode.org, which supports Python and Sage well, but also aims to support other languages like Ruby, R, etc.  Probably the best description of Codenode is "Google docs combined with Mathematica Notebooks".

Answer (score 1):

CodeIDE is an ok one: http://www.codeide.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can practice your SQL [here](http://sqlcourse.com/).